# Restore original position draggable element when it's dropped in the wrong place HTML + Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

Im tryinig to use this code which another spoke of him in another post but that modified a little.

http://jsfiddle.net/fsy37kv4/

I would like when some circle was dropped in a wrong position, the circle restore to the original position.

My issue is when I drag the circle from its initial position I want it to disappear from it so that it is noticed that it is moving, but if I release it in the wrong place it returns to its initial position

### HTML code

```
<div id="bracelet">
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="div2" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag1" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg" ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div3" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag2" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div4" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag3" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div5" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag4" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div6" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag5" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div7" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag6" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div8" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag7" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Button-Red.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div9" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag8" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Button-Blue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div10" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag9" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Button-Lightblue.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div11" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag10" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/ba/Button-Purple.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div12" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag11" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Button-Orange.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div id="div13" class="drop" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img id="drag12" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/Button-Green.svg"  ondragend="dragEnd(event)" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</div>
```

### JS CODE

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    var el = ev.target;
    var parent = el.getAttribute("data-parent");
    
    if(!parent){
        el.setAttribute("data-parent", el.parentNode.id);
    }
    
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", el.id);
    
    
    
        
    setTimeout(() => {
        ev.target.classList.add('hide'); //Ocultamos el elemento al arrastrar , hay que definir la clase .hide en el css de la pagina
    }, 0);
    
    
}

function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); 
    
    
    
    ev.target.classList.remove('drag-over');
    
        // get the draggable element
    const id = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    const draggable = document.getElementById(id);

    // add it to the drop target
    ev.target.appendChild(draggable);

    // display the draggable element
    draggable.classList.remove('hide'); 
    
    
}

function dragEnd(ev){
    if(ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect == "none"){
         var parent = document.getElementById(ev.target.getAttribute("data-parent"));
        
        parent.appendChild(ev.target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blockes = document.querySelectorAll('.block'), 
    boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let dragElem = null;
blockes.forEach(block =>{ 
  block.draggable = true;
  block.addEventListener('dragstart', startDragBlock);
  block.addEventListener('dragend', endDragBlock);
});

function startDragBlock() {
  dragElem = this;
  setTimeout (()=> {
    this.classList.add('hide');
  }, 0);
}
function endDragBlock(){
  dragElem = null;
  this.classList.remove('hide');
  //alert(this.parentNode.id);
}

boxes.forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('dragover', dragBoxOver); 
  box.addEventListener('dragenter', dragBoxEnter); 
  box.addEventListener('dragleave', dragBoxLeave); 
  box.addEventListener('drop', dropInBox); 
})

function dragBoxOver(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.classList.add('hover');
}
function dragBoxEnter(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.classList.add('hover');
  if (this.id == "4") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
function dragBoxLeave(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = '';
  this.classList.remove('hover');
}
function dropInBox(){
  this.append(dragElem);
  this.classList.remove('hover');
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 15px;
}
div {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #058bb4;
  min-width: 130px;
  min-height: 130px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.block {
  cursor: grabbing;
  background-color: #10b6e9;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
.hover {
  background-color: #94e5fa;
  position: relative;
}
.hover::before {
  content: "Пора уже отпускать";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  top: -40px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  min-width: 150px;
}html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='block'>Draggable1</div>
  <div class='box' id="1"></div>
  <div class='block'>Draggable2</div>
  <div class='box' id="2"></div>
  <div class='block'>Draggable3</div>
  <div class='box' id="3"></div>
  <div class='block'>Draggable1</div>
  <div class='box' id="4"></div>
  <div class='block'>Draggable2</div>
  <div class='box' id="5"></div>
  <div class='block'>Draggable3</div>
  <div class='box' id="6"></div>
</div>
```